# Why the question whether some sheaf homomorphism (in the base change of direct images of quasi coherent module) is isomorphism is local?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm reading the Gortz's Algebraic Geometry p.322~p.323 and some question arises.

Consider a commutative diagram of schemes

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X' @>{g'}>> X\\
@V{f'}VV @VV{f}V \\
Y' @>{g}>> Y
\end{CD}$$

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be an $\mathcal{O}_X$-module. We will construct a homomorphism of $\mathcal{O}_{Y'}$=modules

$$g^{*}(f_{*}\mathcal{F}) \to f^{'}_{*}(g^{'*}\mathcal{F})$$

which is functorial in $\mathcal{F}$ as follows. As the functor $g^{*}$ is left adjoint to $g_{*}$, it suffices to construct a functorial homomorphism $v:f_{*}\mathcal{F} \to g_{*}f^{'}_{{*}}(g^{'*}\mathcal{F})=f_{*}g^{'}_{*}(g^{'*}\mathcal{F})$. But again by adjointness the identity of $g^{'*}\mathcal{F}$ corresponds to a morphism $\mathcal{F} \to g_{*}^{'}(g^{'*}\mathcal{F})$ and applying the functor $f_{*}$ we obtain $v$.

If $\mathcal{G}^{'}$ is an $\mathcal{O}_{Y'}$-module we may tensor the above morphism with the canonical homomorphism $\mathcal{G}^{'}\to f^{'}_{*}(f^{'*}\mathcal{G}^{'})$. We obtain a homomorphism of $\mathcal{O}_{Y'}$-modules, functorial in $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}^{'}$.

$$ \psi : \mathcal{G}^{'} \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{Y^{'}}}g^{*}(f_{*}\mathcal{F}) \to f^{'}_{*}(f^{'*}\mathcal{G}^{'}) \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{Y'}}f^{'}_{*}(g^{'*}\mathcal{F}) \to f^{'}_{*}(f^{'*}\mathcal{G}^{'} \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{X'}} g^{'*}\mathcal{F})$$

**My question is**, why the question whether the above homomorphism is isomorphism is local on $Y$ and $Y'$?

We will use next theorem

> Theorem : Let $\mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{F'} \to \mathcal{F''}$ be a sequence of sheaves on $X$. Then following are equivalent.
> (a) $\mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{F'} \to \mathcal{F''}$ is exact.
> (b) There exists an open cover $\mathcal{U} = \{ U_i\}$ such that $\mathcal{F}|_{U_i} \to \mathcal{F'}|_{U_i} \to \mathcal{F''} |_{U_i}$ is exact.

By this theorem, we may assume that $Y^{'}$ is affine open. We want show that we may also assume that $Y$ is affine. Cover the $Y = \cup_{i}U_i$ by affine opens. Then for each $i$, we have a commutative(?) diagram :

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
g^{'-1}(f^{-1}(U_i)) @>{g^{'}_{i}}>> f^{-1}(U_i)\\
@V{f'_{i}}VV @VV{f_i}V \\
g^{-1}(U_i) @>{g_i}>> U_i
\end{CD}$$

, where each morphisms are restrictions of $f',g',f,g$.

Let $\mathcal{F}_i := \mathcal{F}|_{f^{-1}(U_i)}$ and $\mathcal{G}^{'}_i = \mathcal{G}^{'}|_{g^{-1}(U_i)}$. Then similarly as above, for each $i$, we get homomorphism of $\mathcal{O}_{g^{-1}(U_i)}$-modules :

$$ \psi_i : \mathcal{G}^{'}_i \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{g^{-1}(U_i)}}g_i^{*}(f_{i*}\mathcal{F}_i) \to f_{i *}^{'}(f^{'*}_{i}\mathcal{G}^{'}_i \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{g^{'-1}(f^{-1}(U_i))}}g_i^{'*}\mathcal{F}_i) $$

which is an isomorphism by the reduction assumtion.

**My question is, the restriction $\psi |_{g^{-1}(U_i)}$ is same as $\psi_i$?.** If so, then since $\{ g^{-1}(U_i) \}$ forms an open cover of $Y'$, we may apply the above theorem and we are done.

By some calculation involving some commutative diagram I could show that

$(\mathcal{G}^{'} \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{Y^{'}}}g^{*}(f_{*}\mathcal{F})) |_{g^{-1}(U_i)} = \mathcal{G}^{'}_i \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{g^{-1}(U_i)}}g_i^{*}(f_{i*}\mathcal{F}_i)$
and $(f^{'}_{*}(f^{'*}\mathcal{G}^{'} \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{X'}} g^{'*}\mathcal{F})) |_{g^{-1}(U_i)}=f_{i *}^{'}(f^{'*}_{i}\mathcal{G}^{'}_i \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{g^{'-1}(f^{-1}(U_i))}}g_i^{'*}\mathcal{F}_i) $. (true?)

And whether $\psi |_{g^{-1}(U_i)}$ is same as $\psi_i$ is still curious. (It seems that it requires somewhat complex(?) argument, involving more concrete description of the map $\psi$ and $\psi_i$. Is there any simpler method?)

Can any one help?

Comment: I have no time to work out your example in the moment, but I can give you a suggestion: Usually in such a situation to say, "the question is local" in $Y$ and $Y'$ means, one can reduce to the case where $Y$ and $Y'$ are affine. For this it is better to start with reduction to $Y = U$ affine first and then choose an $V \subseteq Y'$ affine, which automatically then maps to $U =Y$ affine. Now consider the big cube diagram that maps the square $X_U U V X_V$ to the square $X Y Y' X_{Y'}$ (with $X_S = X \times_Y S$).
It helps organizing the necessary computations with push-back/forward functors.